# What are the side effects of making primary key nullable number vs non-nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

When using Entity Framework you can define a primary key for your entity class as non-nullable int/long:

```
class Car
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

You can also define the primary key as nullable int:

```
class Car
{
     public int? Id {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to know what are the pros/cons of each of the two options?  Also if i'm using the second option should i annotate the `Id` with `[Required]` attribute?

Comment: Primary key should never be null, otherwise **it isn't a primary key**

Comment: You can get duplicate primary keys

Comment: Shoudn't EF complain about that at startup? I doesn't affect EF in any way...

Comment: you can still query tables without primary keys.

Comment: Why do you need nullable primary key?

Comment: Many people does not understand the question. He isn't asking 'Whether to have nullable pk or not?" he is just asking why EF allows you to have nullable Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary keys are always non nullable. Also they are immutable (at least EF does not allow you to modify them for an existing objects).

There are almost no pros/cons of using any of the two options. But the first (using non nullable type) looks more natural since it matches the database column nullability. However, even if for some reason you use the second option, there is no need to use `Required` attribute or `IsRequired()` fluent configuration because once EF knows it is a primary key (or part of a primary key), it will make the corresponding database column non nullable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your key as NULL and unqiue then make your key as a UNIQUE KEY. PRIMARY key cannot be null. Something like

```
[Index("IX_MyKey", 1, IsUnique = true)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

I am not sure about the Pros of making a Primary key as NULL but as far as the cons is concerned, the only thing is if you will make a Primary key as NULLable then it is no more a PRIMARY KEY. Primary Keys make normalized databases referenceable.